# How to add missing trailing slash on all links (WPCLI or MySQL)

Tags: mysql, wordpress, wp-cli

My website has hundreds of posts containing some links without the ending slash /

I want to be be able to find all these links and add the trailing slash /

For example /dir/this-page becomes /dir/this-page/

Ideally I would prefer to do this via WP-CLI or MySQL.

I did look at Apache rewrite rules in .htaccess but I want the actual post content to update instead.

Comment: Why do you specifically want to update the URLs? What's the benefit over using `htaccess`?

Comment: @BenM it is for SEO reasons. Google prefers links with trailing slashes.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic/duplicate because it's been cross-posted and answered on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/342871/how-to-add-missing-trailing-slash-on-all-links-wpcli-or-mysql

Comment: @leymannx although it wasn't a proper answer and didn't provide a solution.

Comment: You mean url inside post content ?

Comment: @MohammedShafeek yes inside post content.